# How to get root view controller?

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I need an instance of root view controller.

I tried those approaches:

```
UIViewController *rootViewController = (UIViewController*)[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController];
```

Returns:  **null**:

Also when I try to get an array of controllers:

```
NSArray *viewControllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
```

It returns only one controller, but it isn't my root view controller.

If I try to take from navigation controller:

```
UIViewController *root = (UIViewController*)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

Returns:  **null**:

Any ideas why?  What else could I try to get an instance of my root view controller?

Thanks.

Comment: The keyWindow is the active window,for example,when you show a UIAlertView,the UIAlertView's window is the keyWindow but it's not the AppDelegate's window.If you want to get application's rootViewController,maybe use  [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController ] is better.

Answer (score 267, accepted):

if you are trying to access the `rootViewController` you set in your appDelegate. try this:

**Objective-C**

```
YourViewController *rootController = (YourViewController*)[[(YourAppDelegate*)
                                   [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate] window] rootViewController];
```

**Swift**

```
let appDelegate  = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
let viewController = appDelegate.window!.rootViewController as YourViewController
```

**Swift 3**

```
let appDelegate  = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let viewController = appDelegate.window!.rootViewController as! YourViewController
```

**Swift 4 & 4.2**

```
let viewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? YourViewController
```

**Swift 5 & 5.1 & 5.2**

```swift
let viewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController as? YourViewController
```

Comment: YourViewController *rootController =(YourViewController *)[[(YourAppDelegate *)
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate] window] rootViewController];

Comment: In Swift2, you have to use "let appDelegate  = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate", to force  unwrap

Comment: Is there any way to have two controllers assigned in this manner so that you can pull data from  both  to the watch?

Comment: This is a lifesaver. Thank you! Took me months to find this piece of delicious code!

Comment: AVPictureInPictureController or AVPlayerViewController will create new window 
which class is PGHostedWindow and add it to windows array, Therefore, using the first window may cause a crash

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Catalyst. If I try this code from a VC that is presented by my root VC, I get the presented VC, not the root. Looking more closely, each one is in a separate window (I guess Catalyst is doing this). The one I'm really interested in is in UIApplication.shared.windows[1] (not first).

Answer (score 49):

**Objective-C**

```
UIViewController *controller = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
```

**Swift 2.0**

```
let viewController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController
```

**Swift 5**

```
let viewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
```

Comment: This should be the top answer. +1 The other answers will not work if you need to reference the root view controller from a different framework that your main app is dependent on.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that keyWindow was deprecated in iOS13

Answer (score 11):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003562/ios-how-to-segue-back-to-a-uiviewcontroller-thats-already-loaded) by @0x7fffffff, if you have UINavigationController it can be easier to do:

```
YourViewController *rootController =
    (YourViewController *)
        [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex: 0];
```

The code in the answer above returns UINavigation controller (if you have it) and if this is what you need, you can use `self.navigationController`.

Answer (score 10):

For **Swift 5 and later**, I recommend use this method:

```
UIApplication.shared.windows.last?.rootViewController
```

Use **.last** will return top view Controller is active.

**.first** sometimes doesn't work with libraries that require a window on **top & actived**.

For example: **Admob** . I have the ad not showing and find that I am calling the hidden window underneath when using sheet or fullscreenCover.

**NOTE**: View want to display ads required in NavigationView, if not, ads will be not run.

Example: NavigationView { View1() }

I hope it is useful.

Comment: UIApplication.shared.windows.last!.rootViewController has been DEPRECATED in iOS 15.0

Answer (score 6):

**iOS 15**

With Scenes and some APIs being deprecated (like `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow`), the most universal approach I've found is this:

```
let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
    .first(where: { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }) as? UIWindowScene

let rootViewController = scene?
    .windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow })?
    .rootViewController
```

**Note:** If your app truly supports multiple windows/scenes, that means you have multiple "root View Controllers" and this code is not for you :)

Answer (score 4):

Unless you have a good reason, in your root controller do this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(onTheEvent:)
                                             name:@"ABCMyEvent"
                                           object:nil];
```

And when you want to notify it:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ABCMyEvent"
                                                object:self];
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3**

```
let rootViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift way to do it, you can call this from anywhere, it returns optional so watch out about that:

```
/// EZSwiftExtensions - Gives you the VC on top so you can easily push your popups
var topMostVC: UIViewController? {
    var presentedVC = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController
    while let pVC = presentedVC?.presentedViewController {
        presentedVC = pVC
    }

    if presentedVC == nil {
        print("EZSwiftExtensions Error: You don't have any views set. You may be calling them in viewDidLoad. Try viewDidAppear instead.")
    }
    return presentedVC
}
```

Its included as a standard function in:

https://github.com/goktugyil/EZSwiftExtensions

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3: Chage ViewController withOut Segue and send AnyObject** 
Use: Identity  MainPageViewController on target ViewController

```
let mainPage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainPageViewController") as! MainPageViewController

var mainPageNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainPage)

self.present(mainPageNav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**or if you want to Change View Controller and send Data**

```
let mainPage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainPageViewController") as! MainPageViewController

let dataToSend = "**Any String**" or  var ObjectToSend:**AnyObject** 

mainPage.getData = dataToSend 

var mainPageNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainPage)

self.present(mainPageNav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode 15 & iOS 15**

*Objective C*

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window.rootViewController
```

*Swift*

Add below extension:

```
extension UIApplication {
    
    /// The app's key window.
    var keyWindow: UIWindow? {
        let windowScenes: [UIWindowScene] = connectedScenes.compactMap({ $0 as? UIWindowScene })
        let windows: [UIWindow] = windowScenes.flatMap({ $0.windows })
        return windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow })
    }
    
}
```

Usage:

```
let topController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
```