# UIAlertViewController Error

Tags: ios, iphone

How can I use UIAlertViewController in appdelegate class.

[image: Getting error no visibility @interface for appdelegate declare the selector]

Comment: u can't present alert box...!!!

Comment: just `[alert show];`

Comment: @KDeogharkar its UIAlertView, this is UIAlertController and it needs another controller to show it, but rather use UIAlertView for simple showing

Comment: I got your point but in future UIAlertView may not work for ios 9.

Comment: oh sorry @Tj3n . i missed that my mistake.

Comment: UIViewController *vc = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
    [vc presentViewController:showForegroundNotificationAlertController animated:YES completion:nil];
Correct working this one...... Thanks.

Comment: UIViewController *vc = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
    [vc presentViewController:showForegroundNotificationAlertController animated:YES completion:nil];
Correct working this one...... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to show in `UIAlertviewController` in `Appdelegate`, you can do it two ways

**Choice-1**

> Initially you get the visible/Top ViewController from window , assume that you were in some where on any viewcontrollerm at that time you access that from root view controller , use this

```
    UIViewController *vc = [self visibleViewController:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController];
    //second add your present on`UIAlertController`
   [vc presentViewController:alert animated:YES Completion:nil];
```

**For get which viewcontroller at visible** for Reference purpose I take the answer From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22882078/how-to-get-visible-viewcontroller-from-app-delegate-when-using-storyboard)

```
- (UIViewController *)visibleViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController
{
    if (rootViewController.presentedViewController == nil)
    {
        return rootViewController;
    }
    if ([rootViewController.presentedViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
    {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)rootViewController.presentedViewController;
        UIViewController *lastViewController = [[navigationController viewControllers] lastObject];
    
        return [self visibleViewController:lastViewController];
    }
    if ([rootViewController.presentedViewController isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]])
    {
        UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)rootViewController.presentedViewController;
        UIViewController *selectedViewController = tabBarController.selectedViewController;
    
        return [self visibleViewController:selectedViewController];
    }

    UIViewController *presentedViewController = (UIViewController *)rootViewController.presentedViewController;

    return [self visibleViewController:presentedViewController];
}
```

**Swift**

```
 let navigationController = application.windows[0].rootViewController as UINavigationController

  let vc = navigationController.visibleViewController
   vc.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Choice-2**

If you want to present the `UIAlertController` in directly in `Appdelegetae` , do like simple

```
 [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES Completion:nil];
```

**Update**

```
[ [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] presentViewController:alert animated:YES Completion:nil];
```

Comment: Still getting same error....   [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES Completion:nil];

Comment: Thanks for your help bro. but still getting same error.... I m confuse about what should I do. 
    
    UIAlertController *alert=   [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:Title message:message preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];        UIAlertAction *OK = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction  *action){  }];
        [alert addAction:OK];
    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] presentViewController:alert animated:YES Completion:nil];

Comment: @S.Dharmwan -- there is no more choice bro, else do like create a NSObject Class on that class add your UIAlert Controller , then call where you need , it works...