# Presenting alert controller on current displaying view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uiwindow

In my app I am using two storyboard. Main and Main2.

**Main** storyboard has two VCs and first one is embedded to a navigation controller. Likewise for **Main2** storyboard. `-buttonPressed` in FirstVC will **push** to SecondVC in **Main**. `-buttonPressed` in SecondVC will **present** FirstVC of **Main2** storyboard. `-buttonPressed` in FirstVC will **push** to SecondVC in **Main2**.

I have a class NetworkConnection which is a shared instance. When reachability changes I'm calling the following method

```
- (void)internetConnectionAlert {
    NetworkStatus status = [[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] currentReachabilityStatus];

    id obj = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController];

    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]] && (status == NotReachable)) {

        UIViewController *viewController = [[obj viewControllers] lastObject];
        [viewController presentViewController:self.alertController
                                     animated:YES
                                   completion:nil];
    } else {
        [self.alertController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

I run the app. FirstVC of **Main** comes up. I disconnect the network. `AlertController` comes over due to reachability changed. I connect back to network. `AlertController` gets dismissed. Same thing when I go to SecondVC (still in **Main**). So all is good.

I press button in SecondVC and it goes to FirstVC of **Main2**. Now when I disconnect the network no `AlertController` pops up.

So I put some logs around. Turns out when I go from one storyboard to another the rootViewController is not changed to the new navigation controller. The rootViewController is still the navigation controller in **Main** not in **Main2**.

This is the log I put in `-viewDidLoad` of FirstVC in **Main2**

```
NSLog(@"Key window rvc : %@",[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController]);
NSLog(@"self navi   vc : %@",self.navigationController);
```

This prints

```
2016-06-24 18:55:16.622 Navi[12129:3257811] Key window rvc : <UINavigationController: 0x7feaac834800>
2016-06-24 18:55:16.622 Navi[12129:3257811] self navi   vc : <UINavigationController: 0x7feaac832800>
```

And hence I am getting the following warning

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7feaab524490> on <SecondViewController: 0x7feaab657330> whose view is not in the window hierarchy
```

I do get proper result when I put the following code in `-viewDidLoad` of FirstVC in **Main2**.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].rootViewController = self.navigationController;
```

I don't think this is any good because I almost definitely will require the original rootViewController at some point in my code. Also when the project gets bigger using the above code in every VC will be a nuisance.

So how do I get the AlertController to show up on the current ViewController (on screen) regardless of the hierarchical mess.

Thank you for your patience.

**EDIT** : To get a quick overview [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418177/how-to-get-root-view-controller) is what is happening (don't have the nil problem though).

Code for changing storyboard

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
    MainTwoViewController *mainTwoVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main2" bundle:nil] instantiateInitialViewController];
    [self presentViewController:mainTwoVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: could you please provide code of how you are changing the storyboard ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri there you go.

Comment: Try to change the root controller to mainTWoVc after  you present it.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Did you read the whole thing?

Comment: That is the point . You cannot have two root controllers. You can have only one. When you present a vc from a different storyboard, you should change the root controller too. Else you should be using only one storyboard.

Comment: I am asking for workaround.

Comment: There is no workaround. When you present a vc from a different storyboard, it doesn't get added to heirarchy! Either you should make the new on as root controller or you should present the new one from the same storyboard.