# Show an alert when deferring a Promoted IAP request from App Store

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, storekit

We're implementing Apple's new "[Promoted In-App Purchases](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/promoting-in-app-purchases/)" system, allowing users to click a "Buy" button inside Apple's App Store that triggers a purchase of an IAP.

The system calls for the app to implement the `SKPaymentTransactionObserver`'s [`paymentQueue:shouldAddStorePayment:forProduct:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymenttransactionobserver/2877502-paymentqueue?language=objc) delegate method, which returns a boolean. The documentation says,

> Return `true` to continue the transaction in your app.
>
> Return `false` to defer or cancel the transaction.

If we simply return `false`, the user sees our app come to the foreground and then nothing else happens. By default, the OS doesn't pop up a message saying "Purchase canceled" or anything like that; it leaves that decision up to the app developer, I suppose.

The App Store Promoted IAP purchase request can arrive at any time, including when the user is in the middle of a flow that shouldn't be interrupted. It's a perfect case to return `false` from this method. When I do that, I'd like to show the user an alert message explaining the problem with [`UIAlertController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller).

The problem is, I have no context view controller to use inside my `paymentQueue:shouldAddStorePayment:forProduct:`. Normally, when I want to show an alert from inside a view controller, I'd call `[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];`, but `self` in this delegate method is a `SKPaymentTransactionObserver`, not a view controller, so that won't work.

I'm not even sure that there *is* a guaranteed active view controller when this delegate method fires. For all I know, the delegate method could fire prior to the `applicationDidBecomeActive` event.

What's the best way to show an alert (or any other snippet of UI) when returning `false` from `paymentQueue:shouldAddStorePayment:forProduct:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [get the application window's root view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418177/how-to-get-root-view-controller) and use that to present the alert.

**Objective-C**

```
id *rootController = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate] window] rootViewController];
[rootViewController presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**Swift**

```
let appDelegate  = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate
let viewController = appDelegate.window!.rootViewController
viewController.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: What are the details need to be shown

Answer (score 1):

Have a shared instance of a class that conforms to `SKPaymentTransactionObserver`. Store the promoted payment in an optional variable of this shared instance.

```
class StoreHelper: NSObject, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

    static let shared = StoreHelper()

    private var promotedPayment: SKPayment?

    var hasPromotedPayment: Bool {
        return promotedPayment != .none
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()

        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    }

    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, shouldAddStorePayment payment: SKPayment, for product: SKProduct) -> Bool {
        promotedPayment = payment

        return false
    }

    func beginPurchaseForPromotedPayment() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Place the presentation code in the `viewDidAppear` of the first view controller that appears.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if StoreHelper.shared.hasPromotedPayment {
        // your presentation code

        StoreHelper.shared.beginPurchaseForPromotedPayment()

        // after completion, remove promoted product from store helper
    }
}
```

Happy Coding