# rootViewController not loading after calling it, using -> present(viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, rootviewcontroller

My rootViewController works and loads fine. However, when I call it using the `present(viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)` from another viewController I get nothing but a black screen.

I looked all over the stackOverflow but only found solutions for storyboard users. I am doing this programmatically

```
@objc func handleLogin() {
    print("LOGIN BUTTON TOUCHED")
    guard let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text else {
        print("Form is not valid.")
        return
    }
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        let viewController = RootViewController()
   ***  self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("Logged in")            
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use Dispatch.main to present the viewController?

Comment: no I haven't. How do I do that?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418177/how-to-get-root-view-controller

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with `self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)`

I think your `RootViewController()` is already presented. The black screen you see is might be the one without any data? I am not sure, will need your code for that class.

Another approach you can consider is to replace the real `rootViewController` from current `uiWindow` like this

```
@objc func handleLogin() {
  print("LOGIN BUTTON TOUCHED")
  guard let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text else {
    print("Form is not valid.")
    return
  }

  Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { [weak self] (user, error) in
    guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
    guard error == nil else { return }
    guard let user = user else { return }

    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = RootViewController()
    print("Logged in")            
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you've created a new instance(RootViewController) and it must be black .. your not referring to your RootViewController

Comment: How do I refer to the RootViewController?