# how to return to previous view controllers in current view controller?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I want to return to previous view controllers from current one. the situation is like this:
A,B,C,D are view controllers. A presents B, B presents C, C presents D. i know use delegate can from D to C, C to B, B to A. Now i want to return to A from D directly. How to do this? 
Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I do believe this is a duplicate question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003562/ios-how-to-segue-back-to-a-uiviewcontroller-thats-already-loaded

Comment: i didn't use uinavigationcontroller. its just normal view controllers.

Comment: You might want to use `UINavigationController` and push/pop rather than modal transitions and present/dismiss.

Comment: I see UINavigationController is a better solution. I wonder if normal view controller, can we still do the same ?

Comment: If I understand your question, once you have your navigation controller, the view controllers that you navigate within there are just plain old controllers, nothing fancy. You just need to replace your `[self presentViewController ...]` references with `[self.navigationController pushViewController ...]`. And replace `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated ...]` with `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated ...]`. (Or if using segues, replace modal segues with push segues.)

Comment: This way, you can use all of the tools that chimgrrl and Woodenlabs suggested. Much easier way to jump "back" multiple controllers (from D to A, for example).

Comment: @Rob thanks, maybe i need to read UINavigationController guide.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use below statement:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];
```

or

```
for (UIViewController *vc in [self.navigationController viewControllers]) {

    if([vc isKindOfClass:[A class]])
    {
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:vc animated:TRUE];
    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: If I don't use navigation controller, just normal view controller, this still can work?

Comment: How did you push from one view controller to another view controller? Can you post your moving code here?

Comment: i use  presentViewController and dismissViewController methods

Comment: maybe i need to change to UiNavigationController, thanks for your anser.