# How to display previous view controller in background with partial transperent

Tags: iphone, object, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Now i was currently in a view controller **UsersViewController**

i need to open a new viewController **ModelViewController** by tapping a button

i opened it by following code

```
-(IBAction)openModelView:(id)sender
{
   ModelViewController *modelView= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ModelViewController"];

    [self presentViewController:modelView animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

But **in the newly opened modelView in background i need to display previousView ie UsersViewController.view**

I set **alpha 0.7 for modelView** but there is black background in background

but i need to display previousView ie UsersViewController.view

How is it opssible

Comment: i don't know why but it's not working anyhow so why don't you go with add that viewController as addSubview rather then presenting it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use navigationController or dismissViewController.

This may help: [How to segue back to a UIViewController that's already loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003562/ios-how-to-segue-back-to-a-uiviewcontroller-thats-already-loaded)