# How to jump to any other controller in iOS?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, segue

My storyboard structure is like:
[image]

A is a navigation controller
B is a tab bar controller
C,D,E are view controllers
F,G,H,I,J are a view controllers

if now i am on I ,and there's a button the i pressed then I go back to C.How to do that?
I tried make segue between I and C, but C has a back button, you pressed it,you back to I.
I don't want that.when i came from I to C, i want C is as I first come to C from B.

if i want to go to H from I,I want H have a back button that you pressed and you back to F not to I.

Comment: if you want  custom transition of views. its better to perform segues through programatically than connecting them modally..

Comment: you can follow this question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003562/how-to-segue-back-to-a-uiviewcontroller-thats-already-loaded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From I to C: do popViewController twice, or loop through the navigationcontroller's viewcontrollers and find C, pop to C.

From H to I: Programmatically push to I. In storyboard set an storyboard ID for I, and you can create a I instance through [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:ID];

Answer (score 0):

I would set the `viewControllers` property of `UINavigationController`.

Create an array of View Controllers like you would desire the stack to be. Example: @{C, F, I} or in the case of your question you would use @{ C } then update the navigationController to contain these views.

```
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:(NSArray *)];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something other than what your Segues are set up for, be sure to give your VC a stoyboard ID [image: like this]

Then using that storyboard ID, you can call this code to create/display;

```
-(IBAction)myButtonAction:(id)sender{
    RDLaunchOptionsTableViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RDLaunchOptionsTableViewController"];
    vc.delegate = self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

You don't have to use a nav controller. Just use [self presentViewController....];